Mongodb aggregation merge a document to an existing collection
I m trying to merge a document to an existing collection. This document can be a new one or an existing one. If it exists, update with the new one. But there is one issue.
Below is the collection
[
  {
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "NOT_SURE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_id": 101,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      }
    ]
  }
]

The document has an array of products and if the document to be merged contains a product which already exists and a product which is new, then the existing one should replace old one and the new one should be added.
The product are identified by their names.
Below is the document to update with:
[
  {
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bag",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      }
    ]
  }
}

The collection after the merge should look like below:
[
  {
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "NOT_SURE"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bag",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_id": 101,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      }
    ]
  }
]


It seems like you previously created a similar question. If both questions ask for the same problem, I suggest closing one.

I thought the question wasn't very clear. I will close the other one

Is demo you are looking for?

The other answer works. Thanks

This question is similar to: MongoDB aggregate merge condition. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
